# TFS deploy, place additional attributes in web config

Tags: c#, tfs, web-config

I'm try to figure out why TFS add attributes to my web config file for smtp client.
For example i have a little bit difficult password with ~ ' : .

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="testmail.com" userName="testusername" password="545:~'usernametest" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

After TFS deploy i got this

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="testmail.com" userName="testusername" password="545:'usernametest&quot; -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:3 -retryInterval:3000" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

~ was deleted, and `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:3 -retryInterval:3000` was added.

I had a parameters file to customize config file with password via TFS deploy.

```
  <parameter name="password" defaultvalue="123">
    <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\Web.config$" match="/configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network/@password" />
  </parameter>
```

With a simple passwords like 123 i don't get that problem.
How can i prevent it? Or i need to store password in TFS deploy with additional characters?

Comment: Do you have a web.debug.config and web.release.config? Can you please right click on web.debug.config and select Preview Transform? What does it show?

Comment: Also, what is in your web.release.config (if you have that file?) The transformations are defined there.

Comment: Sorry my late response, i will try different approach to resolve my problem. The problem that VSTS create additional characters for every escape characters like ', & e.t.c. and i have no idia how i can prevent it. Nothing extraordinary in the web.release.config it is the same like source config.

Comment: Ok, Good luck :)

Comment: @Evgeny How did you deploy your project? Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share your build definition and detailed steps of the deployment? I'd like to reproduce your issue on my side.